# Clarifying Bearing off

Tags: backgammon

At the end of the game (bearing off), which of the following moves are valid?

[image: two posible moves]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, the second one is not valid.**

There are many different rule sets for Backgammon.  However, I'm unaware of any which would allow it.

This quote is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon).  It is footnoted as coming from both *Backgammon for Winners*, and *Hoyle's Rules of Games*.

> A die may not be used to bear off checkers from a lower-numbered point unless there are no checkers on any higher points.